# Mongodb Bulk write Updateone or Updatemany

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulk

I want to know if its faster(importing) using `updateone` or `updatemany` with bulk write.My code for importing the data into the collection with pymongo look is this:

```
for file in sorted_files:
    df = process_file(file)
    for row, item in df.iterrows():
        data_dict = item.to_dict()
        bulk_request.append(UpdateOne(
            {"nsamples": {"$lt": 12}},
            {
                "$push": {"samples": data_dict},
                "$inc": {"nsamples": 1}
            },
            upsert=True
        ))
    result = mycol1.bulk_write(bulk_request)
```

When i tried update many the only thing i change is this:

```
...
...
bulk_request.append(UpdateMany(..
..
..
```

I didnt see any major difference in insertion time.Shouldnt updateMany be way faster?
Maybe i am doing something wrong.Any advice would be helpful!
Thanks in advance!

Note:My data consist of 1.2m rows .I need each document to contain 12 subdocuments.

Comment: `updateOne` increases the round trip time. Use `updateMany` instead, by pushing the values to an array before inserting. Let me known if you want a sample code.

Comment: @hhharsha36 Thank you.Yes a sample code would be very helpful if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Wernfried Domscheit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) answer is correct.

This answer is specific to your scenario.

If you don't mind not updating records to existing documents and insert new documents altogether, use the below code which is the best optimized for your use case.

```py
sorted_files = []
process_file = None
for file in sorted_files:
    df = process_file(file)
    sample_data = []
    for row, item in df.iterrows():
        sample_data.append(item.to_dict())
        if len(sample_data) == 12:
            mycol1.insertOne({
                "samples": sample_data,
                "nsamples": len(sample_data),
            })
            sample_data = []
    mycol1.insertOne({
        "samples": sample_data,
        "nsamples": len(sample_data),
    })
```

If you want to fill up your existing records with 12 objects and then,
create new records, use the below code logic.

> Note: I have not tested the code in my local, its just to understand the flow for you to use.

```py
for file in sorted_files:
    df = process_file(file)
    sample_data = []
    continuity_flag = False
    for row, item in df.iterrows():
        sample_data.append(item.to_dict())
        if not continuity_flag:
            sample_rec = mycol1.find_one({"nsamples": {"$lt": 12}}, {"nsamples": 1})
            if sample_rec is None:
                continuity_flag = True
            elif sample_rec["nsamples"] + len(sample_data) == 12:
                mycol1.update_one({
                    "_id": sample_rec["_id"]
                }, {
                    "$push": {"samples": {"$each": sample_data}},
                    "$inc": {"nsamples": len(sample_data)}
                })
        if len(sample_data) == 12:
            mycol1.insert_one({
                "samples": sample_data,
                "nsamples": len(sample_data),
            })
            sample_data = []
    if sample_data:
        mycol1.insert_one({
            "samples": sample_data,
            "nsamples": len(sample_data),
        })
```

Comment: Yes you are right..Before to insert 1.2m rows i neeed 6 hours,,now with your code and wernfrieddomscheit code i need 5 minutes

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I aprreciate it a lot

Comment: i just have one question..what is the purpose of this line of code?    mycol1.insertOne({
        "samples": sample_data,
        "nsamples": len(sample_data),
    }) in the first code you sent me?why are you doing another insert after the for?

Comment: Let say there are only 4 documents to be inserted after the `continuity_flag` check. These 4 records won't be inserted since there have to be 12 records for the if condition to pass. That's why there is an additional `if` condition, in the end, to check and insert these records.

Answer (score 1):

`updateOne` updates only the **first** matching document for `nsamples: {$lt: 12}`. So `updateOne` should be faster.

However, why do you insert them one by one? Put all in one document and make a single update. Similar to this one:

```
sample_data = [];
for row, item in df.iterrows():
    data_dict = item.to_dict();
    sample_data.append(data_dict);
db.mycol1.updateOne(
  {"nsamples": {"$lt": 12}},
  { 
     "$push": { samples: { $each: sample_data } },
     "$inc": {"nsamples": len(sample_data) }
  }
)
```

Comment: I am using bucket pattern for timeseries https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/time-series-data-and-mongodb-part-2-schema-design-best-practices  i tried to do something similar like them.Yes i will try your code

Comment: I tried your code..did some changes to convert it to python but it doesnt seems to work..

Comment: I need each document to contain 12 subdocuments.